# RefreshUser in Authentication Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm following this [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html) with UserInterface and I want to understand refreshUser()

I logging in, and change the username ( foo -> bar )  in my database, change the page but the user is still logged with name bar.

In this part of [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#understanding-serialize-and-how-a-user-is-saved-in-the-session) I can read that for security reason the user will be logged out

Comment: Weird. Maybe it's cache fault?

Comment: Interesting link.  Never knew username was checked on refresh.  Can you logout then log back in with the new username?

Comment: This isn't a question.